# How to do the Proof of P(A ∪ (B ∩ C))?

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics

The answer should be given by this image:

[image]

This is how I imagine the problem in picture form, with the red being the area we would want to find. Following this logic you would just want P(A ∩ B) + P(A ∩ C) wouldn't you?

[image]

Comment: How would you know that B and C do not intersect?  The diagram does not show that possibility.

Comment: You're right I'm not sure why I didn't think of it. However, how would you know that they do intersect?

Comment: You wouldn't but you would have to allow for it in the formula.  If they do not intersect the intersection term would be null.

Answer (score 1):

One way to approach this algebraically is to note that $Pr(a) = E[A]$, where $A$ is a random variable that takes value 1 when event a occurs and 0 when event a does not occur. Logical expressions with your events can then be converted into algebraic expressions. For instance, $Pr(a~\text{and}~b) = E[AB]$, since $AB$ takes value 1 only when both $A$ and $B$ both take value 1. Further $Pr(a~\text{or}~b) = E[A+B-AB]$; you can check that $A+B-AB$ takes value 1 if either A, B, or both take value 1, but it takes value 0 when both take value 0.

Now, your expression can be proven algebraically:

\begin{align*}
Pr(a~\text{and}~(b~\text{or}~c)) &= E[A(B+C-BC)] \\
&= E[AB + AC - ABC] \\
&= E[AB] + E[AC] - E[ABC] \\
&= Pr(a~\text{and}~b) + Pr(a~\text{and}~c) - Pr(a~\text{and}~b~\text{and}~c)
\end{align*}